# Conditions to make $\frac{\sqrt{\lambda_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}}{\sqrt{(\lambda_1-\lambda_3)(\lambda_1-\lambda_2+\lambda_3)}}$ well-defined

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

everybody. I'm working in some topic and I need to imposse conditions for that the following expression is well defined

$$ f(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3})=\frac{\sqrt{\lambda_{1}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2})}}{\sqrt{(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{3})(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3})}}$$ donde  $(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Mi attempt,
We need that the expresion

$$\lambda_{1}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2})>0\hspace{6mm}(1)$$

and

$$(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{3})(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3})>0\hspace{6mm}(1)$$

From (1) we have

$$(\lambda_{1}>0, \hspace{3mm}\text{and} \hspace{3mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}>0) \hspace{3mm}\text{or}\hspace{3mm} (\lambda_{1}<0, \hspace{3mm}\text{and} \hspace{3mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}<0)\hspace{5mm} (2)$$

and

$$(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{3}>0, \hspace{3mm}\text{and} \hspace{3mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}>0) \hspace{3mm}\text{or}\hspace{3mm}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{3}<0, \hspace{3mm}\text{and} \hspace{3mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}<0)\hspace{5mm} (4)$$

But  I don't know what to do from here, since for instance, from (2) I've

$$(\lambda_{1}>0 \hspace{2mm} \text{or} \hspace{2mm} \lambda_{1}<0)\hspace{2mm} \text{and}\hspace{2mm} (\lambda_{1}>0 \hspace{2mm} \text{or} \hspace{2mm} \lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}<0)\hspace{2mm} \text{and}\hspace{2mm} (\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}>0 \hspace{2mm} \text{or} \hspace{2mm} \lambda_{1}<0)\hspace{2mm} \text{and} \hspace{2mm} (\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}>0 \hspace{2mm} \text{or} \hspace{2mm} \lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}<0) $$

But I'm stuck here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm unsure what sort of expression you're looking for. In my eyes, simply stating $\lambda_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_2) > 0$ and $(\lambda_1-\lambda_3)(\lambda_1-\lambda_2 + \lambda_3)> 0$ is sufficient to ensure $f$ is well-defined. Are you looking for conditions on $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ that don't make use of the other two?

Comment: On its domain of definition, your function is equivalent to
$$f(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_3)(\lambda_1-\lambda_2+\lambda_3)}},$$
which has a domain of definition 'twice as large'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$\lambda_1=a,\lambda_2=c,\lambda_3=b$, then basically we have :

$$\begin{cases}(a-b)(a+b-c)>0\\
a(a-c)≥0\end{cases}$$

---

If $a=0$, then $b(b-c)<0$ . If $a≠0$, then you have :

$$\begin{cases}a>0\\ a≥c\end{cases}\tag {1a}$$

or

$$\begin{cases}a<0\\a≤c\end{cases}\tag {1b}$$

Similarly, for $(a-b)(a+b-c)>0$, we have :

$$\begin{cases}a>b\\a+b>c\end{cases}\tag {2a}$$

or

$$\begin{cases}a<b\\a+b<c\end{cases}\tag {2b}$$

Therefore, except the trivial case $a=0$, then the rest of the solution becomes :

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases} a>0\\
a≥c\\
a>b\\
a+b>c\end{cases}\thinspace \vee\thinspace \underbrace{\begin{cases} a>0\\
a≥c\\
a<b\\
a+b<c\end{cases}}_{\text{no solutions exist}}\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}\underbrace{\begin{cases} a<0\\
a≤c\\
a>b\\
a+b>c\end{cases}}_{\text {no solutions exist}}\thinspace \vee\thinspace\begin{cases} a<0\\
a≤c\\
a<b\\
a+b<c\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Finally, we conclude that : $($ except the trivial case $a=0$ $)$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\begin{align}\begin{cases} a>0\\
a≥c\\
a>b\\
a+b>c\end{cases}\thinspace \vee\thinspace\begin{cases} a<0\\
a≤c\\
a<b\\
a+b<c\end{cases}\end{align}}$$

---

$\rm {Comment :}$

Here, I leave the rest to you to make some *possible* elementary algebraic simplifications . As a comment, I find it correct to say that it is *not* possible to reduce all cases to one .

Comment: Thanks  @Ione Student.