# Doubt with the the operator $\lor$ combined with $\land$.

Tags: logic

While working with a system of equations, $L=M$ the following roots were obtained:

$f(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3})=\frac{\sqrt{\lambda_{1}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2})}}{\sqrt{(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{3})(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3})}}$, where $(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

$ g(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3})=\frac{\sqrt{\lambda_{2}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2})}}{\sqrt{(\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})}}$, where $ (\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

In this thread [Conditions to make $\frac{\sqrt{\lambda_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}}{\sqrt{(\lambda_1-\lambda_3)(\lambda_1-\lambda_2+\lambda_3)}}$ well-defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741298/conditions-to-make-frac-sqrt-lambda-1-lambda-1-lambda-2-sqrt-lambda)  we have that the first root $f$ is well defined if, and only if

$a)$ $\lambda_1\geq 0$, $\lambda_2\leq \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2-\lambda_1<\lambda_3<\lambda_1$

ó

$b)$ $\lambda_1\leq 0$, $\lambda_2\geq \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_1<\lambda_3<\lambda_2-\lambda_1$

Then the question arose: which of the roots do I want to exist? Thus, the following cases emerged:

$1.$ $f$ exists, and $g$ does not exist.

$2.$ $g$ exists, and $f$ does not exist.

$3.$ Both $f$ and $g$ exist.

For case $1.$ it requires the following cases:

$1.1.a$ The equation $a)$ is satisfied, and $g$ is not well-defined.

$1.1.b$ The equation $b)$ is satisfied, and $g$ is not well-defined.

For case
$1.1.a$, I made this reasoning, and this is where my doubt arises. First, I'll explain what I tried to do, and then I'll present my doubt: Note that equation $a)$ has among its conditions that $\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}>0$. Thus, if we want $g$ to not be well-defined, we must have $(\lambda_{2}<0)\hspace{2mm}\lor\hspace{2mm} (\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})<0$ (I did not put $\lambda_{2}\leq 0$ here due to specific issues with the problem). This gives us the following sub-cases:

$1aa.$ [$\lambda_{1}> 0\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}> \lambda_{2}\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{3} \hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}>0$] $\land$ $[\lambda_{2}<0]$ $\land$ $[\color{red}{(\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})>0}]$

$1ab.$  [$\lambda_{1}> 0\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}> \lambda_{2}\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{3} \hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}>0$] $\land$ $\color{red}{[\lambda_{2}<0]}$ $\land$ $[\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3}>0 \hspace{2mm} \land \hspace{2mm}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})<0]$

$1ac.$ [$\lambda_{1}> 0\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm} \hspace{3mm} \lambda_{1}> \lambda_{2}\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm} \hspace{3mm}\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{3} \hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}>0$] $\land$ $\color{red}{[\lambda_{2}<0]}$ $\land$  $[\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3}<0 \hspace{2mm} \land \hspace{2mm}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})>0]$

$1ad.$ [$\lambda_{1}> 0\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}  \lambda_{1}> \lambda_{2}\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{3} \hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}>0$] $\land$ [$\lambda_{2}<0$] $\land$ $[\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3}>0 \hspace{2mm} \land \hspace{2mm}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})<0]$

$1ae$ [$\lambda_{1}> 0\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm} \lambda_{1}> \lambda_{2}\hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{3} \hspace{1mm}\land \hspace{1mm}\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}>0$] $\land$ [$\lambda_{2}<0$] $\land$ $[\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3}<0 \hspace{2mm} \land \hspace{2mm}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{3})>0]$

My questions are:

1. Should I consider what is marked in red or not? I am having problems with the inclusive logical connector $\lor$ since in case $1.a$ I have an expression in the form:$a\land (b\lor c)$ . I tried to analyze the cases above considering that the $\lor$ connector is true if (b) is true $\lor$ if (c) is true $\lor$ if (b and c) are true. However, I'm unsure if, for example, if I make (b) true, I should make (c) no true as well, which is what is marked in red in case $1aa$. (Is the inclusive
   $\lor$ marked in red correct, or is it just exclusive $\lor$)?
2. Is there any more direct way to see case $1.a$?
3. Is there any computer program that calculates these cases? Sometimes they are very extensive, and I'm afraid of getting lost.

Thanks in advance!